# @future callout + button + multiple clicks = multiple callouts instead of one

Tags: apex, custom-button, callout, future

I have a button(with Javascript for call apex class) in Opportunity object.
I have Apex Class with @future Callout for sending information about Opportunity to Jira.
And it's work fine, except one stupid thing.

If i click on this button several(for example:5) times (before any of Callout's happens)
then i create 5 duplicates tickets in Jira with same info about this Opportunity.

Question is: how to disable button after first click?
note: i've tried to add "this.style.display = hidden" (or something like this) in javascript button, but button dissapears only after callout completed
,also
i've tried to add restriction inside class but it do not help

[image]

**First image** - ideal world 1 click on button, 1 jira issue, opportunity filled and restrict to click on this button

**Second image** - real world some accidentally click several times, several callouts created and send info to jira, after that first response fill the field in opportunity and disable button. But it is too late because we already create several jira tickets.

**Any ideas?**

JS button code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}; 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")}; 
if ("{!Opportunity.Jira_Ticket__c}" != ''){ 
alert('You already have a Jira issue, please find "Deal Desk Link" below.'); 
} 
else 
{ 

var ortj = '{!Opportunity.Request_type_Jira__c}'; 
var stringOrtj = ortj.toString(); 

////////////////////// 
//Verification required fields 
////////////////////// 
...

////////////////////// 
//Execute class + method 
////////////////////// 

sforce.apex.execute("JIRAConnectorWebserviceCalloutCreate","createIssue", {objectDescription: description_value , objectHead:"[{!Account.Name}] {!Opportunity.Name}", projectKey:"MSDD", issueType:"Project", issuePriority:"{!Opportunity.Priority_Jira__c}", OppId: "{!Opportunity.Id}", dueDate: "{!Opportunity.Due_date_Jira__c}", presaleRequestType: stringOrtj, customerName: "{!Account.Name}", Reporter : Reporter}); 
location.reload(); 

} 
}
```

Comment: In the button, update a checkbox field on the opportunity and check for that field to be true in the button - if it is true, do not call out. When the callout is finished, uncheck the field on the opportunity.

Comment: Please post your button & JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your button code hard to say if this will "fit" into your model but...

A simple solution below

1. Add a field on the opportunity called JIRA_Request_Sent__c
2. In your button, before the callout, mark the field true and update the opportunity
3. In your button present an error if the field is true
4. On your update of the opportunity with the JIRA ticket number, uncheck the box.

You could also not do this as an @future but that all depends on your use case.

Comment: this simple test show's me that i can't change field in opportunity and check if it changed, because javascript on button "compiled" with old value:

{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")}
var Opportunity = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
Opportunity.id = '006c000000DaTXg';

Opportunity.Region__c= 'value4';
sforce.connection.update([Opportunity]);



if ({!ISPICKVAL( Opportunity.Region__c , 'value4')}){
alert('123');
}

Comment: i think i will try this method inside callout, something like:
        //if opportunity is locked, just ignore all code below
        //here we should lock Opportunity
        //only if Jira-response is fail - then unlock.

But it will be on monday =)

Comment: You don't check if it is changed. you query for the record, check the value, if false, update record to true.......

Comment: final solution in JS button:
`{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")}
var Opportunity = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
Opportunity.id = '006c000000DaTXg';


var opp_region = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Region__c FROM Opportunity WHERE id = '{!Opportunity.Id}'");

records = opp_region.getArray("records");

  for (var i=0; i< records.length; i++) {
    var record = records[i];
  
  }

if (record.Region__c == 'value8'){
alert('please stop');
}
else{
Opportunity.Region__c= 'value8';
sforce.connection.update([Opportunity]);
alert('once');
//do code here
}`

Answer (score 1):

I would consider dropping the @future annotation & using the (relatively) new [Queueable interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm).

The main benefit is that when you use this interface, you are given a job ID:

```
ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(new AsyncExecutionExample());
```

You could then use an actionPoller (for example) to query the status of this job:

```
AsyncApexJob jobInfo = [SELECT Status,NumberOfErrors FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id=:jobID];
```

You can then disabled your button until the Queueable job is complete:

Comment: Thank you for idea. i think i will learn about this a bit later. Previous idea looks more easy.